# Error while executing the Windows command through a batch file.

Tags: sql-server-2008, command-line

I have remote login permission to this server and this server is ping-able from my system but still I am getting the following error message. Can any one tell me why I am getting this.
Thanks.

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : SQL Server Network Inte
rfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : A network-related or in
stance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server
. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and i
f SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see
 SQL Server Books Online..
```

Comment: It could be, that you are trying to connect to incorrect SQL server instance name, or the network protocol your client is trying to connect to the SQL server is not enabled on the server (i.e TCP/IP, Named Pipes, etc.). What is the command, including parameters which you are executing please and how do you have your SQL Native Client configured?

Comment: Thnaks Chainik , instance name was sppelled incorrectly. Now its working for me.

Comment: I used sqlcmd -L command to get the list of all sql instances and found the correct instance name. Thnak You